# How to split an ordered dataframe into first half and second half

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I want to pass a data frame to a function which splits it into two halves but retains the order (e.g. 10 row df and rows 1-5 are in one returned df and rows 6-10 are in the other returned df). I'm trying to use the function `split()` to( return a list of the 2 dfs but when I use `sample()` it mixes up the orders.

```
split_df<- function(df)
{
  test = split(df, sample(1:2,length(df)/2))
  return(test)
}
```

I'm having trouble with the inputs for `sample()`. I know people have asked about splitting data frames here but I can't get this to work for some reason. What else can I use besides `sample()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the `sample` function may be throwing you off. It's intended for **random** sampling.  Try `rep()` instead:

```
split_df <- function(df) {
   test <- split(df, rep(1:2,each=length(df)/2))
   return(test)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this also in a very basic way

```
split_df <- function(df) {
      df1 <- df[1:ceiling(length(df[ , 1])), ]
      df2 <- df[ceiling(length(df[ , 1])):length(df[ , 1]), ]
      return(list(df1, df2))
}
```