# How to split an ordered data frame into first half and second half multiple times in R

Tags: r

I would like to split my data frame into multiple halves based on the ordering of one column so that I can have a column containing "first half" and "second half". For example, I want the data to look like this:

```
1 - first half
2 - first half
3 - second half
4 - second half
2 - first half
3 - first half
4 - second half
5 - second half
```

Here is code to reproduce the basic structure the data

```
order <- data.frame(test = c(1:10, 4:13, 6:15))
```

and here is code to reproduce the desired output:

```
order$halves <- c(replicate(5, "firstHalf"), replicate(5, "secondHalf"), 
                  replicate(5, "firstHalf"), replicate(5, "secondHalf"), 
                  replicate(5, "firstHalf"), replicate(5, "secondHalf"))
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261980/how-to-split-an-ordered-dataframe-into-first-half-and-second-half) about splitting a data frame, but I don't know how to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way in base R -

```
order$group <- rep(1:nrow(order), each = 5, length.out = nrow(order))

first_half <- order[order$group %% 2 == 1, ]
second_half <- order[order$group %% 2 == 0, ]
```

Output -

```
first_half
   test    halves group
1     1 firstHalf     1
2     2 firstHalf     1
3     3 firstHalf     1
4     4 firstHalf     1
5     5 firstHalf     1
11    4 firstHalf     3
12    5 firstHalf     3
13    6 firstHalf     3
14    7 firstHalf     3
15    8 firstHalf     3
21    6 firstHalf     5
22    7 firstHalf     5
23    8 firstHalf     5
24    9 firstHalf     5
25   10 firstHalf     5

second_half
   test     halves group
6     6 secondHalf     2
7     7 secondHalf     2
8     8 secondHalf     2
9     9 secondHalf     2
10   10 secondHalf     2
16    9 secondHalf     4
17   10 secondHalf     4
18   11 secondHalf     4
19   12 secondHalf     4
20   13 secondHalf     4
26   11 secondHalf     6
27   12 secondHalf     6
28   13 secondHalf     6
29   14 secondHalf     6
30   15 secondHalf     6
```

You can also use `split(order, f = order$group %% 2 == 1)` which generates a list of dataframes with each half.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a way to do it if the groups are uneven? Sorry, I hadn't thought about that when I was making my simple example.

Comment: @Lisa A pattern/rule can be coded. If there's no pattern/rule then there's no code. Is there a pattern/rule in the uneven-ness?

Comment: I do know how many are in each group, but there's no pattern. Perhaps it will be easier to split it apart, use this code, and put it back together. Thank you!

Comment: @Lisa Are you simply looking to divide the dataset into two random halves?

Comment: No, there's a order to it. There are frames of time of measurement (each frame is 10 ms), which are split into categories (before, during, after). I need the first and second half of before and after.

Comment: @Onyambu, ```halves``` are what I am trying to produce.

Comment: @Onyambu `halves` needs to be generated. I didn't go for `split` because it's only 2 dataframes in this question. But yes, `split(order, order$group %% 2 == 1)` is valid as well.

Comment: @Lisa if you have a column indicating categories then a more generic solution is easily possible.